# Wildcard for loading filenames into array

Tags: javascript, three.js, wildcard

I am making my first steps with JavaScript and playing with Three.js too.

The thing is that I made a cube map using the following code to randomly select a group of 6 images:

```
var imgAr = [
    'sources/instagram2/image_1.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_2.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_3.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_4.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_5.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_6.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_7.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_8.jpg',
    'sources/instagram2/image_9.jpg',
];

var urls = imgAr.sort(function(){return .6 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);
```

So the 6 sides of my cube will change everytime that I reload my site.

Now my problem is that instagram2 is a folder with a big quantity of images with the same name (image1, image2, image3, etc) and it will be constantly updating.

Is there a way to change my code and specify inside imgAr that i want to use all the images inside instagram2 with the prefix `"image_"` ?

Thank you very much for your help. This is a really important project for me and i am doing the best trying to learn how to code.

Update: I tryied this but it still doesnt working:

```
            var nrString = "000";

            images = [
                    'sources/instagram2/image' + nrString + ".jpg",
                    'sources/instagram2/image' + nrString + ".jpg",
                    'sources/instagram2/image' + nrString + ".jpg",
                    'sources/instagram2/image' + nrString + ".jpg",
                    'sources/instagram2/image' + nrString + ".jpg",
                    'sources/instagram2/image' + nrString + ".jpg"
                    ];

            var urls = images.sort(function(){return .6 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);
            var reflectionCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls, THREE.CubeReflectionMapping );
```

Comment: Well, you'll require PHP to send that array to JS

Comment: And do you know how can i do it? Thank you

Comment: In this specific case you'll need to generate a AJAX call from JAVASCRIPT and Hit a php service that returns this array after reading from the File system itself. Have a look at JQuery Ajax (since it handles most of the complex functionalities) which is also Cross browser compliant

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Akshay i will take a look at JQuery Ajax

Comment: In case you find any issues please update the question here. Glad to help :)

Comment: Hello @AkshayKhandelwal I updated the question with the code that I made and it still doesnt working. Do you have any idea?